# For a space X and metric space Y, if X is compact then uniform and compact convergence topology coincides

Tags: general-topology, function-spaces

In the book Topology by Munkres, there is a theorem: Let $X$ be a space and $(Y,d)$ be a metric space.  For the function space $Y^X$ ,one has the following inclusions of topologies: $uniform\supset compact convergence \supset pointwise convergence $. I have done this. The next part says: If $X$ is compact,  the first two coincide and if $X$ is discrete the second two coincide. I am stuck in the next part. Please help.

Answer (score 4):

Compact convergence means uniform convergence on compact sets. If $X$ is already compact, then there is uniform convergence on the entire space $X$, so both topologies coincide.

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you please give some hint for the part, when $X$ is discrete, the 2nd two topologies coincide.?

Comment: @Unknown In a discrete space all compact subsets are finite so compact convergence is just finite convergence (and this is easily seen to be just pointwise convergence).